# What would provoke 'iterators are incompatible' when comparing iterators from one single vector?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, iterator, shared-ptr

I'm working on a UI. The base class for a UI component is `UILayout`, and the entire UI is a tree of UILayout objects, with the root being a UILayout representing the entire screen. In order to contain this hierarchy, any given UILayout has a vector ***mChildren*** of `boost::shared_ptr<UILayout>`.

A UIManager object takes care of Updating the entire hierarchy of UILayouts. Each call to Update iterates over the vector mChildren, calling Update on each child recursively.

Because changing the shape of the vector would invalidate those iterators, adding and removing entries from mChildren is confined to the ResizeChildren method. When components need to be added or removed, they are added to one of two vectors, mChildrenPendingAddition and mChildrenPendingRemoval. Immediately before the Update loop, ResizeChildren is called, and mChildren is updated accordingly. (Please stop me if this is an asinine way of handling this particular problem.)

I'm getting an exception when I attempt to remove from mChildren all entries which are also contained in mChildrenPendingRemoval. From UILayout::ResizeChildren():

```
mChildren.erase(remove_if(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(),
    IntersectsWithChildrenPendingRemoval(this)), mChildren.end());
```

IntersectsWithChildrenPendingRemoval's comparison function calls this->ChildrenPendingRemovalContains(HUILayout ly), which does the following:

```
return (find(mChildrenPendingRemoval.begin(), mChildrenPendingRemoval.end(),
    ly) != mChildrenPendingRemoval.end());
```

That line *sometimes* fails the debug assertion **vector iterators incompatible**. There are plenty of existing questions on this error, but it seems like it normally indicates that two iterators from different containers are being compared. But here, that's clearly not the case, right? What else could cause this problem?

Relevant source code:

- [Class and predicate definition](http://awforsythe.com/files/iteratorsincompatible_0.gif)
- [Implementation of the offending methods](http://awforsythe.com/files/iteratorsincompatible_1.gif)

This is a plugin that I'm developing for a multi-threaded application. The fact that the problem crops up at very rare and random intervals leads me to believe it has something to do with the fact that the plugin is running in separate threads, but all of these methods are called from a single function, squarely in a single thread, and mChildren is not accessed or modified in any other thread.

Comment: Have you tried any locking to verify that the problem is indeed not a threading race condition?

Comment: @MichaelPrice The application I'm writing the plugin for is multi-threaded, so it calls certain functions of my plugin concurrently. Beyond ensuring that those parts of the plugin don't intermingle in unsafe ways, I'm not doing any locking on my end.

The best I've been able to do is to make sure that mChildren is accessible in only one branch of execution, which should (to the best of my knowledge) have only a single thread running it at any given time.

Comment: Maybe an error at a different place (buffer overrun, race condition involving a pointer, ...) corrupted your container?

Answer (score 0):

> Please stop me if this is an asinine way of handling this particular problem

Why don't you work on a copy of the collection, and swap it in at once:

```
std::list<X> copy(mChildren);

copy.insert(...);
copy.remove(...);
copy.insert(...);

// at once:
std::swap(copy, mChildren);
```

Further thoughts:

- it is in general not very convenient to keep iterators into mutable containers around for any period of time
- Since this is a container of smart-pointers... ***why don't you pass the smart-pointers themselves around*** if you needed to keep 'pointers' to elements? (Of course, that wouldn't enable iteration, but that is IMO not a very healthy desire anyway)

Comment: Thank you very much for making me aware of my potential asininity. To be clear, std::swap _would_ still invalidate any iterators on mChildren, correct? So, as before, I should ensure that the swap occurs at a point when no such iterators are in play.

Comment: @awforsythe: in fact, not until `copy` would go out of scope/invalidates _it's_ iterators. You'd need to be aware, though, that the iterators now point to elements of a _different_ container :)

Comment: As to your second point: I'm currently iterating (recursively) over the list when ticking/updating each component, when drawing each to the screen, and when calling various input methods (OnClick, OnStartDrag, etc). Currently, because those last two occur in a different thread, I keep a separate, parallel copy of mChildren named mDisplayList for those to iterate over. I do indeed keep the smart pointers for other purposes, but I don't see an alternative to iteration unless I make it impossible to add and remove child components at runtime. Is this the sad reality, or am I missing something?

Comment: You could of course use an observer pattern with appropriately locked model. I'm getting the impression that most of your trouble seems to stem from the view not being separated from the model (data)

Comment: I would agree with you there, and in any case I've been getting the notion lately that my current implementation is filled with too many reactionary band-aid solutions and could stand to be a whole lot cleaner. I believe I'm going to step back and see how I might reorganize this system with these answers in mind. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Just use indices instead of iterators.
Iterators are overrated. They are nothing more than general pointers. The best way to manage items in a vector was and is allways to use indices. If you want to use iterators, try std::list, in this case iterators won't be invalidated even if you add elements to the list or remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd be just fine without iterators, so I'll give that a try. In that case, I suppose the alternative to remove_if would be to loop over mChildren in reverse, check each element, and call mChildren.erase(mChildren.begin() + i)?

(I think I mistakenly clicked the 'not helpful' button, which was most certainly not my intent.)

Comment: Please reconsider this answer.  Iterators are NOT pointers.  Indices may not be as efficient as iterators.  `std::list` will never be faster than `vector`, and often a lot slower.

Comment: @awforsythe: If you did, it didn't take. Downvoting requires 125 reputation.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: Indices should be about as fast as iterators, for `std::vector`.  Performance on other containers will vary.

Comment: The standard library algorithms work with iterators. They don't work with indices. That's a pretty significant advantage to using iterators.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: Iterators called generalized pointers not by me, but by almost every C++ tutorial. Nobody ever said they are the same as the C pointers, pointers does not only mean C pointers. Iterators store the same information as a pointer (the location of the object, or an object relative to it), and its type determines where is the next/previos object. Iterators are smarter than pointers, but interally they are the same.